# Present data from firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I retrieve data from Firestore in my viewmodel, but they don't show up on the screen, why?

ViewModel:

```
class ListScreenViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

val listStates: MutableState<ListScreenState> =
    mutableStateOf(ListScreenState.Default)



fun getDataFromFirebase() {
    launch {
        val db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val listTD = mutableListOf<ListTD>()
        db.collection("ListTD")
            .whereEqualTo("userUID", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid.toString())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents.documents) {
                    val des = document.getString("description")
                    val lab = document.getString("label")
                    val col = document.getString("colour")
                    val finDate = document.getString("finishDate")
                    val uUID = document.getString("userUID")
                    val docID = document.id

                    Log.i(docID,"LogID")
                    Log.i(des,"des")



                    val listTDItem = ListTD(
                        description = des,
                        label = lab,
                        colour = col,
                        finishDate = finDate,
                        userUID = uUID,

                    )


                    listTD.add(listTDItem)


                }


            }
        listStates.value = ListScreenState.Success(lists = listTD)
    }
  }
}
```

Screen:

```
fun ListScreen(
    navigation: INavigationRouter,
    viewModel: ListScreenViewModel = getViewModel()

) {

var lists = remember { mutableStateListOf<ListTD>() }
val context = LocalContext.current

viewModel.listStates.value.let {
    when (it) {
        ListScreenState.Default -> {
            viewModel.getDataFromFirebase()
        }

        is ListScreenState.Success -> {

            lists.clear()
            lists.addAll(it.lists)

        }


    }
}

Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(title = {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.YourToDayLists))
        })
    },

    ) {
    MainScreenContent(
        paddingValues = it,
        lists = lists,
        navigation = navigation,
    )
}

Button(onClick = { navigation.navigateToAddListScreen() },
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Black),
    modifier = Modifier
        .offset(x = 270.dp, y = 720.dp),


    ) {
    Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.Add), fontSize = 20.sp, color = Color.White)

}

}

@Composable
fun MainScreenContent(navigation: INavigationRouter,
                      paddingValues: PaddingValues,
                      lists: MutableList<ListTD>
){

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier

            .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp),

        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {


        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(paddingValues)

        ){

            lists.forEach {
                item(key = it.description) {
                    TaskRow(list = it, onRowClick = {
                        it?.let {
                            navigation.navigateToDetailScreen(it.description.toString(),it.label.toString(),it.finishDate.toString(),it.colour.toString())
                        }
                    }, colorString = it.colour.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}





@Composable
fun TaskRow(
    list: ListTD,
    onRowClick: () -> Unit,
    colorString:String
){

Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = onRowClick)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(vertical = 8.dp, horizontal = 16.dp)
        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
        .background(Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor(colorString)))
        .wrapContentHeight()

        ,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center



) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start) {
        Text(text = list.description.toString(), fontSize = 20.sp)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(text = list.label.toString(), fontSize = 15.sp)

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Log.i(list.description, "LELE")

        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.FinishTo) + list.finishDate.toString(), fontSize = 15.sp)



    }
  }
}
```

I try everything, i dont know where is problem

Comment: A. Do those log messages have the data and B. is the `is ListScreenState.Success` called?

Comment: yes and yes, I just tried and when I click on the button to add an element and return to this screen the data is loaded

Comment: I cannot spot the issue at first glance. However, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Comment: I can't spot an issue either. I'm still trying to understand where it breaks, I don't think Firebase is your issue though. It's probably a Compose issue. Do you see the correct item count in the LazyColumn?

Comment: When I first load the screen the lazycollumn is empty, but when I go to another screen and come back it has all the elements in it